# Create new NSDate object from the date returned from UIDatePicker

Tags: iphone, nsdate, uidatepicker

How to create new NSDate object from [myUIDatePicker date] ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to create a new NSDate object, you can just use the one it gives you.

```
NSDate *chosenDate = myDatePicker.date;
```

Comment: I want to get multiple dates from the picker, so I think I need to create multiple object and then insert those dates in the NSMutableArray.

Comment: You can just do `[array addObject:myDatePicker.date]` whenever you want to add a date.

Comment: But somehow the object I inserted is out of scope. My guess is myDatePicker.date will not be returned the new NSDate object every time...

Comment: Yes, myDatePicker.date gives you the date it's set to. What do you mean it's out of scope? Can we see some code?

Comment: You probably didn't initialize the array with enough capacity via `arrayWithCapacity`

Comment: No, `arrayWithCapacity` is just a suggestion for the array, you can still add more objects.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to create a new NSDate object, then you may call `[myUIDatePicker date]`.